# Web Application with data editing capabilities by users stored in Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext, ext-js

I have been using GeoExt/Extjs/Openlayers/Geoserver for some time.I have created a web application for mapping features in a county.I wanted to know whether there is a way I can add (edting/Addnew feature) capabilities on my application with authentication which reads the users on Geoserver.

This is how I expect it to work; All viewers can see the features but when they click on addNew button , an authentication window pops up for them to login.The people allowed to edit are the users of the office whose usernames and passwords are on Geoserver.

Is this possible and if yes, how?